# SybSQLException: Syntax error during explicit conversion

Tags: java, sql, spring

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с ошибкой. У меня POST метод в spring, передаю в хранимую процедуру 2 параметра - 2 строки. в одну из них записана xml

```
"@coords_xml" -> "<parameters><parameter><name_param>X</name_param><value_param>59.937371</value_param></parameter><parameter><name_param>Y</name_param><value_param>30.312891</value_param></parameter><parameter><name_param>Radius</name_param><value_param>15.0</value_param></parameter></parameters>"
```

когда дергается метод

```
Map<String, Object> result = super.execute(inParams);
```

вызывается супер метод класса

```
package org.springframework.jdbc.object;

public abstract class StoredProcedure extends org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlCall
```

и возвращается ошибка.

```
18:22:37,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Syntax error during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value '15.0' to a INT field.
```

почему такая ошибка как ее устранить и почему именно на 15.0 валиться я же еще и другие числа передаю и все оке.

Спасибо.

да метод хранимки

```
private void declaredParams() {
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("@operation_alias", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("@coords_xml", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet(RESULT, resultMapper));
        compile();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема была во внутреннем драйвере sybjdbs написал класс переписывающий оригинал.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/303340)

Comment: @Padawan, а поподробнее?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому, что "Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для **исчерпывающих** ответов на вопросы"